# How to kill 'invisible' process using port

Tags: linux, kill, port

On a linux machine, am trying to start Glassfish server.

```
./startserv
```

This returns the following message:

```
There is a process already running using the admin port 4848 -- it is probably another instance of a Glassfish server
```

Have tried to identify which process this is with the following command:

```
lsof -t -i tcp:4848
```

On another machine on which Glassfish is running, this command returns the process id used by Glassfish. However, on the machine on which we are having the issue, nothing is returned.

What is the best way to identify and kill the process using port 4848, given that the `lsof -t -i tcp:4848` is not helping?

Thanks

Comment: Try the same command as root. Any progress?

Comment: `netstat -tlp | grep 4848` or `ss -tlp | grep 4848` ?

Comment: Neither return anything.  ss -tlp | grep 4848 works on the server on which Glassfish is running, but not netstat -tlp | grep 4848

Comment: did you try it *as root user*? That makes a difference.

Comment: the other way round: `pgrep glassfish` ? (or whatever the name)

Comment: @Archemar This assumes `glassfish` is the culprit. Without such assumption  `pgrep` cannot be used "to identify and kill the process using port 4848". I'm not saying your idea is useless. I'm posting this comment because I think assumptions like this should be stated explicitly to avoid other assumptions (especially from the OP) which may turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski agreed.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two things going on here. One is that there is something listening on the port and lsof and friends are missing it or the startup script/error message is confused.

Network namespaces may hide the port, but if you want to directly query the proc filesystem try

```
grep 12f0 /proc/net/tcp
grep 12f0 /proc/net/tcp6
```

12f0 is 4848 in hex and those files are where the kernel stores the information about TCPv4 and TCPv6 sockets.

If you get matching lines then there really is a something listening to the port and your tools are sus.  No hit means either you have namespaces in play or the startup script is playing up.

You can also check if the socket is really in use with netcat

```
nc -l 4848
```

If its silent then its ok, if it complains about socket in use, then it really is in use and you need to check your tools are ok and namespaces.